# SizeToFit on a UITextView vertically centered in a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

[RESOLVED]
My mistake... details was a UILabel instead of a UITextView. And sizeToFit does not resize a UILabel. Replacing the UILabel by a UITextView resolve my problem.

---

I have a fixed height custom cell with all the constraints to vertical center a view (called 'content') that contains a title and description. Content View hierarchy is:

- icon
- header
- content UIView

  - title UILabel
  - details UITextView
- footer

When I test the value of 'details' in interface builder everything works fine on the preview (xCode 6): details is resized to contain the text and 'content' is vertically centered.

But when setting by code the content of 'details' and calling `sizeToFit`, the UITextView is properly resized BUT constraints are not updated. See below the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code. What do I miss ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // get a cell
    QZSetupPartyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PackCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // fill the current cell with the current pack
    QZPack *pack = self.party.packs[indexPath.row];

    // set pack title
    cell.title.text = pack.json[@"title"];

    // resize textview to its content
    cell.details.text = pack.json[@"desc"];
    [cell.details sizeToFit];

    // async load of the icon
    [pack loadIconWithCompletion:^(UIImage *image) {
        cell.icon.image = image;
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    }];

    // and recompute the cell constraints
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the xib?

Comment: Sorry not enough reputation to do so.